# How to get count of records for some specific where condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data in which there are 2 columns: 
USER_ID and CONTRACT_ID. There can be 'n' number of users in a contract id.

```
1    0303000
2    0303000
3    1234567
1    0303000
2    0303000
3    1234567 
1    0303000
2    0303000
3    1234567
1    0303000
2    0303000
3    1234567
```

Now i want something like this:

```
Count    CONTRACT_ID
8        0303000
4        1234567
```

Someone please help me how to create a sql query to get this kind of result.

Comment: A review of any basic tutorial would be highly advisable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a `GROUP BY` on `CONTRACT_ID` and `COUNT(*)`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as count,
  CONTRACT_ID 
FROM 
  table1 
GROUP BY 
  CONTRACT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Group By`

```
SELECT count(*) as `Count`,CONTRACT_ID 
from tablename Group By CONTRACT_ID
```